# Function handler does not work on dynamically created element(not the event!)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Before you down vote as duplicate,hear me out!

I have an app, it generates a table from PHP code, after accessing the database.

The HTML is very simple:

```
<h2>Find food by name</h2>




<form method="post">
<label for="food">Food</label>
<input type="text" id="food" name="food">
<input id="submitBtn" type="submit" name="submit" value="View Results">
</form>

<a href="index.php">Back to home</a>

<?php require "templates/footer.php"; ?>
```

The body elements opening tag is in the header.php file.

Here is the JS, we can skip the PHP and SQL code, these work fine.

```
$(function(){
if(jQuery){
alert("i am here"); // check if jQuery is loaded, it is.
}

if($('table').length == 0) {
alert("table is not generated yet"); // check if table is there, works as planned
}
else {
var reso = $('table').id="mainTable"; //assigning ID to the generated table
alert("table id is "+ reso); // testing ID assigment, this works
$(document.body).on('click', '#mainTable', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$('#mainTable').fadeOut(200).fadeIn(2000);
});

}
});
```

I am using "on", the proper jQuery version, but this does not work, there is no error message in the console. I have tried #submitBtn instead of $document.body, I have tried with and without preventDefault().

What I want is just hide the table for a brief moment once it is generated and then fade it in. As of now, it's just generated and displayed, no animation.

I am running this on localhost obviously, no codepen link.

EDIT, found the solution, it really was the CSS opacity set to anything but default causing this. Even the vanilla ID assignment was alright.
However, there is a thing here, the Fade methods work ok,but the slide, hide, show methods do not work as expected. The animations are only visible for a very brief moment.

EDIT, after testing the available jQuery methods...
FadeToggle and chaining like

```
 fadeOut(100).delay(200).fadeIn(300)
```

are really really bad.
The only acceptable way was to run a callback after fadeOut like so:

```
if($('table').length > 0) { $('#mainTable').fadeOut(100, function() {
$('#mainTable').fadeIn(2000);
});}
```

All other methods are too jerky, I did not even dare to use animate().
The above with the CSS set to display none is just smooth enough.

Comment: `What I want is just hide the table for a brief moment once it is generated`  So why have you attached it to the click handler?.

Comment: You mean, I should try something like if(if($('table').length > 0) {
$('#mainTable').fadeOut(200).fadeIn(2000);}
?

Comment: It appears that the code within `else` will never run.

Comment: @heybignick it does run, at least the first 2 lines do

Comment: @Keith
if($('table').length > 0) { $('#mainTable').fadeOut(200).fadeIn(2000);}  does not work either.

Comment: Just do it inside you jquery ready.  Also like people have said, `.id=` is the wrong way to assign id in jquery.

Comment: @Keith, well I have changed the id assignment, it looks like both worked.
Could it be that setting the tables opacity to 0 in the CSS file is affecting this? It still does not work.

Comment: `Could it be that setting the tables opacity to 0 in the CSS file is affecting this?` , it could indeed.   jquery uses the display:none after a CSS fade, so if you want it initially hidden that might be better.

Comment: @Keith I have updated the answer, all the code was fine. Incredibly, it was the CSS opacity set to 0, which I have only done randomly to test something else. wow. I will try with display none now.

Comment: What about [`$('#mainTable').fadeToggle();`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/)? And only use opacity when you are using `.animate(...)`

Comment: @Xorifelse, just tested all these.
Am almost inclined to do this in plain JS. Here is why:
FadeToggle and chaining like fadeOut(100).delay(200).fadeIn(300) are really really bad.
The only acceptable way was to run a callback after fadeOut like so:
if($('table').length > 0) { $('#mainTable').fadeOut(100, function() {
    $('#mainTable').fadeIn(2000);
});} 
All other methods are too jerky, I did not even dare to use animate().
The above with the CSS set to display none is just smooth enough.

Comment: Keep in mind when using animate on CSS level, the browser takes care of the process. Meaning you are executing code on software that is closer to the CPU meaning faster in execution, especially on mobile devices. I was intimidated by it at first but once you get the hang of it it is actually quite effective.

Comment: @Xorifelse, hm, well, I try to do that if I see a possibility, I am not sure if this would work with just adding and removing classes.

Comment: You saying you don't even dare to touch animate kinda asked for a response. [Just see what it can do for you](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/). That is just a simple example (take a look at the fading in) of what it can do.

Comment: @Xorifelse, I am aware of that CSS framework, it's great. I meant the jQuery animate() method, now that one really sucks:-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153994/discussion-between-xorifelse-and-ptts).